# Need to capture data from RTCPeerConnection.getStats() using selenium python [webRTC]

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I have created an application using python selenium-webdriver where 1st browser say(FF) initiates a video call and another browser say (Chrome) accepts the call and starts exchanging Audio and Video data.

While the active video call, I want to capture the webrtc-internals data. I am able to capture that data by locating those elements using selenium but looking for a more stable way to capture the same data as JSON using python.

I have researched alot and found that there exists RTCPeerConnection.getStats() API which provides the same data in JSON but I am unable to use the same in python.

Please help me to do the same.